# The specified value 'Install' is invalid SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

I have a project that installs an SQL server using a command line string. The string worked fine of SQL Server 2012 Express but now I am trying the same string using SQL Server 2014 Express Service Pack 1 and the installation fails and I receive this error in the summary log.

My command:

```
SQLServer2014SP1-KB3058865-x64-ENU.EXE /qs /ACTION=Install 
      /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME="CLIMET01" 
      /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" 
      /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" 
      /TCPENABLED="1" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

Error:

> The specified value 'Install' is invalid. To run in unattended mode, you must specify a valid ACTION. The valid values for ACTION are: '  None  RemovePatch  Uninstall  Install  Upgrade  Patch  Repair  LandingPage  ClusterReport  RunRules  PrepareFailoverCluster  CompleteFailoverCluster  InstallFailoverCluster  RemoveNode  AddNode  EditionUpgrade  Bootstrap  ComponentUpdate  Help  RebuildDatabase  RunDiscovery  PrepareImage  CompleteImage  ConfigureImage'
>
> HResult : 0x858c000d
> FacilityCode : 1420 (58c)
> ErrorCode : 13 (000d)
>
> Data:
> SQL.Setup.FailureCategory = InputSettingValidationFailure
> actionValue = Install

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried asking Microsoft support? `Install` is listed in valid values, so maybe you should report it as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

You are not installing SQL Server Express but a service pack "upgrade package", hence `Install` is probably invalid. Try using `Upgrade` or `Patch`

See: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46694

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 SP1 Update - this package contains the
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 **update to be applied to
>   existing SQL Server 2014 installations**.

See also: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samlester/2015/05/26/sql-server-2014-service-pack-1-unattended-setup-error-the-specified-value-upgrade-is-invalid/

Try this link for installation files:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53167